# Download multiple files and zip into one file using JsZip librabry, but it throwing error when i try to zip larger files, Meteor Nodejs

Tags: node.js, meteor, jszip

Below code works fine for upto 350mb of data and if i try with large files then 503 service unavailable error is thrown.
JszipUtils librabry is used.

```
        var datas = [
          {"link": "http://localhost:3000/cdn/storage/VdrFilesCollection/6qDDBALvZSzvobCBt/original/6qDDBALvZSzvobCBt.xlsx"},
          {
            "link": "http://localhost:3000/cdn/storage/VdrFilesCollection/CstCuHJRHnkLhnnS6/original/CstCuHJRHnkLhnnS6.ts"
          }
        ]//example urls

var zip = JsZip();
        var fileCount = 0;
        var zipFilename = "Pictures.zip";
        // you can do
        if (childNodeCount == totalNodes) {
          datas.forEach(function (url, i) {
              JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(`${url.link}?download=true`, function (err, data) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                throw err; // or handle the error
              }
              zip.file(url._id+'.'+url.ext, data, { binary: true })
              fileCount++;
              if (fileCount == datas.length) {
                console.log(url.link);
                zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob'}).then(function (content) {
                  FileSaver.saveAs(content, zipFilename);
                });
              }
            });
          })
      }
```

Comment: How do you deploy your app? Is there a limit on nginx side?

Comment: may i know what is the question of deployment?

Comment: Depending on whether use galaxy or self hosted it's a difference in default nginx config